# solr + haystack + django where do I place schema.xml?

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I just installed `Solr` and `Haystack` for a `Django` project I'm working on. Following [this](http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/tutorial.html) `Haystack` tutorial I created a schema.xml but I'm not sure where to place it in the Solr installation.

My `Solr` installation is in a directory like this: `/solr` and I'm starting the `Solr` service from `/solr/example` with this command `java -jar start.jar`.

Any ideas where to place that schema.xml and how to tell Solr to use it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solr looks for schema.xml in the ./conf directory under the "Solr home" directory.

See this page for more info.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ConfiguringSolr

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with the details of the core your've created. Ideally the first step of using `solr` would be creating your core like this

`./bin/solr create -c haystack` where haystack is the name of your core

Now you can see a new directory has been created as `./server/solr/haystack/conf` which is where `schema.xml` should be copied into.